# All of my Sqlitedatabase rows to a simple excel

Tags: java, android, eclipse, excel, sqlite

- So far i have manage to do a excel file and just save down some data from my sqlite.db
- Question: How can i save all my rows in the Sqlitedatabase to a excel file? Any tips for a
  beginner? Thanks! Example code? Have been following a guide Sqlite to
  Excel. I know how to get only the first data from the database but i dont know how to get them all? Is it the best way to use Cursor here?
- `db.query(SELECT * FROM MYTABLE)` I want to take all rows and all the data in the rows and then display inside of the excel document. `c.setCellValue(item_id);`

  ```
    db.queueall(SELECT * FROM table2 where Datum='mars')
  ```

  Only show the information from a specific row (All rows in that row)

  ```
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID));
    String getREG = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_REGNR));
    String getMATAR = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_MIL));
    String getDATE = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_DATUMNOW));

   Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    Cell c = null;

     CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();

     CellStyle cs_row = wb.createCellStyle();
     cs_row.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);

     Sheet sheet1 = null;
     sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Tankningsrapport");

     // Generate column headings
     Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);
     Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(1);

     c = row.createCell(0);
     c.setCellValue("Tankning");
     c.setCellStyle(cs);

     c = row.createCell(1);
     c.setCellValue("Datum");
     c.setCellStyle(cs);

     c = row.createCell(2);
     c.setCellValue("REGNR");
     c.setCellStyle(cs);


     c = row1.createCell(0);
     c.setCellValue(item_id);
     c.setCellStyle(cs_row);

     c = row1.createCell(1);
     c.setCellValue(getDATE);
     c.setCellStyle(cs_row);

     c = row1.createCell(2);
     c.setCellValue(getREG);
     c.setCellStyle(cs_row);

     sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
     sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
     sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));
  ```

Comment: I save them to a CSV file (semicolon separated). This is accepted by default in Excel - and saves me from putting another third party library in my app

Comment: The problem is not how to save the file. I just wonder how i can save all my data to the excel file.

Comment: I gave you an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for that Vyger, But that wont help me now :) Maybe 4 weeks ago i would have been really happy about that.

Comment: I do so, to share data from dbs to the Microsoft world... I use the least third party libraries I can, to keep the app small in size and performing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it worked for me!

```
SQLiteAdapter helper = new SQLiteAdapter(visaRapporter.this);
     helper.openToWrite();
     ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<String>();

     Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

       //New Workbook
       Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();


       CellStyle cs_row = wb.createCellStyle();
       cs_row.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);

       //New Sheet
       HSSFSheet sheet1 = null;
       sheet1 = (HSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Tankningsrapport");

       // Generate column headings
       HSSFRow rowHead = sheet1.createRow((short) 0);

       // Head rows

       rowHead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Registerings nummer");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Mätarinställning i km");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Datum");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Månad");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Tankad mängd");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("Tankställe");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue("Signatur");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue("Kontroll Olja: ");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue("Ringtryck VBG: ");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue("Ringtryck bil:");
       rowHead.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue("Ringtryck trailer:");
       int i = 1;
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           HSSFRow rowHead1 = sheet1.createRow((short) i);
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(cursor.getString(1));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(cursor.getString(2));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(cursor.getString(3));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(cursor.getString(4));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(cursor.getString(5));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(cursor.getString(6));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(cursor.getString(7));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(cursor.getString(8));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue(cursor.getString(9));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue(cursor.getString(10));
           rowHead1.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue(cursor.getString(11));
           lis.add(cursor.getString(2));
           i++;
       }
       for (int j = 0; j <= lis.size() - 1; j++) {
           Cursor cursor2 = mySQLiteAdapter.query("select * from Tanking1 where Datum ='" + lis.get(j) + "'");
           while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
               sheet1 = (HSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Tankningsrapport");
               HSSFRow rowhead1 = sheet1.createRow((short) 0);
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Registerings nummer");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Mätarinställning i km");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Datum");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Månad");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Tankad mängd");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("Tankställe");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue("Signatur");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue("Kontroll Olja: ");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue("Ringtryck VBG: ");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue("Ringtryck bil:");
               rowhead1.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue("Ringtryck trailer:");

               HSSFRow rowlow = sheet1.createRow((short) 1);
               rowlow.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(1));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(2));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(3));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(4));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(5));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(6));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(7));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(8));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(9));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(10));
               rowlow.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue(cursor2.getString(11));
           }

       sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (10 * 250));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (10 * 400));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (10 * 400));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(3, (10 * 400));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(4, (10 * 400));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(5, (10 * 400));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(6, (10 * 400));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(7, (10 * 350));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(8, (10 * 350));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(9, (10 * 350));
       sheet1.setColumnWidth(10, (10 * 350));


       // Sparar ner till fil.
       File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
       FileOutputStream os = null;
       Toast.makeText(visaRapporter.this, 
                 "Filen är nu sparad och omgjord från databasen till Excel.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
       try {
        wb.write(os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       Log.w("FileUtils", "Lägger till xls filen" + file);
       }

       }
```

In the for/while list i count each row from the database and put it to new rows into the .xls file!